# Norton equivalent of $Y$ circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I have to find the Norton equivalent for the circuit external to $ R_2 $ (not sure if that's the way to say it, I'm translating from Spanish). The problem is that I don't even understand what's going on in the diagram.

[image: Circuit]

Are $ E_1 = + 12V $ and $ E_2 = -4 V $ different ends of a single voltage source or two separate ones? And in any case, where do I place the "open terminals" of the circuit when I remove $ R_2 $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voltage is the difference of potential between 2 points. Here you have 3 potentials (+12V, -4V and ground which is used as a reference for 0V), that means you have 2 voltage sources.
For example, you can consider that there is a 12V voltage source between E1 and ground, or a 16V voltage source between E1 and E2, etc.

Try to redraw your schematics using this, then you might recognize a more familiar circuit and be able to draw the equivalent Norton circuit for $R_2$. If not, try another combination.

Comment: Answering late, but this cleared up my main question regarding the power sources and then it was clear how to redraw the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

For understanding, let's redraw the circuit in a different way.

[image]

Now you have the voltage sources with series resistances can be converted to current sources with parallel resistances and I hope now you can find the Norton equivalent circuit